# Is the solution/approach provided in my text book wrong?

Tags: probability

Question:

> From a set of 100 cards numbered 1 to 100, 1 card is drawn at random. The probability that the number obtained on the card is divisible by 3 or 4 but not by 12 is?

Solution(textbook):

> A={4,8,12,....100} => n(A) = 25;

> B={3,6,9,....99} => n(B) = 33;

> (A n B) *divisible by 12* = {12,24,....96} => n(A n B) = 8

> Using sets formula i.e., n(A U B) = n(A) + n(B) - n(A n B) => 25 + 33 - 8 = 50

> Thus probability of P(A U B) = 50/100 = 1/2 = 0.50

My Attempt:

> When i tried solving using brute force method in c++, favorable outcomes are 42 but not 50 as stated in textbook. So my answer is 42/100 = 0.42. Kindly confirm correct answer. Thankyou.

My code:

```
int main(){
    int count=0;
    for(int i=1; i<=100; i++){
        if((i%3==0 || i%4==0) && i%12 != 0)
            count++;
    }
    cout<<"TOTAL possible values: "<<count<<endl;
}
```

Comment: 1> This is Mathematics community not a coding community. 2> you are counting the numbers divisible by 3 and not by 12. You haven't considered divisibility by 4.

Comment: well given both sets A and B, both the sets consist of 8 numbers which are divisible by 12 i.e., {12,24,36,48,60,72,84,96}. Shouldn't we remove these  values from both the sets A and B, which makes n(A) = 25 and n(B) = 17. Thus we have 42 elements in total and not 50.

Comment: Your code is beyond me, I don' even see where you accounted for $i\mod 4\equiv0$. Regardless, I tested this with random integers in a python script and indeed it turns out that 42/100 seems to be the correct answer.

Comment: Apologies, I hadn't copied my code right as Im new to asking questions here. I have updated my question  with the actual code. Please have a look

Answer (score 2):

The textbook is wrong and your code is right.

The textbook has double-counted the numbers divisible by $12$ (by counting numbers divisible by $3$ and again for numbers divisible by $4$), so it needs to subtract them off twice -- but it only does it once.

Answer (score 1):

```
i%3==0 && i%12 != 0
```

This condition is not the same as 'divisible by 3 or divisible by 4 and not divisible by 12'

Counterexample: i=4, 8...

Comment: Yes, I have corrected my code now, please have a look. Thankyou

Comment: @MohammadSanaullah You have already pointed out the mistake of the textbook in your comment, so I don't need to explain it anymore

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation @durianice. I'll try to better evaluate my questions the next time I post here .